Escaping Expression Language in nifi
In nifi in the UpdateAttribute processor I'm trying to change 1 attribute with a nifi expression language and don't want to render that attribute in this processor. Later in a process group I will define a needed attribute and will use a ${attribute:evaluateELString()}. To escape rendering I use $$
In this case I have 2 levels of "nesting".
Example:
$${numer_1:multiply($${number_2})}

And result is:
${numer_1:multiply($${number_2})}

I want a result like this
${numer_1:multiply(${number_2})}

How hot can I get that result?
I've tried some variations of that expression with different numbers of $ but it didn't get me a proper answer.
Maybe it's a bug or there is a solution that I didn't know?
PS I use nifi 1.24.0
